# Send string data with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a web project for the university, so I am dealing with AJAX for the first time.
Basically, I would like to create a platform for restaurant employees to manage orders, tables, reservations, and so on.

This is the window to add dishes to an order:
[image]

So far I have only interacted with my API by submitting forms. What I would like to achieve here, is that when I click on the + or - symbols, the related dish must be inserted in the database.

Below I will just put a few pieces of code that have to do with my problem.

**update.js:**

```
    $(document).on("click", ".add-menuItem-button", function () {
        var id_comanda = $(this).attr("data-id_comanda");
        var id_menu = $(this).attr("data-id_menu");

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/projects/programmazione_web/api/dettagli_comanda/create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: id_comanda, id_menu,
            success: function (result) {
                // added to order, notify
                bootbox.alert("Aggiunto alla comanda");
            },
            error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                // show error to console
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                bootbox.alert("Errore");
            }
        });
```

The following are the PHP functions.

**create.php:**

```
// prepare object
$dettagli_comanda = new dettagliComanda($db);

// get id of record to be edited
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// make sure data is not empty
if (
    !empty($data->id_comanda) &&
    !empty($data->id_menu)
) {
    // set property values
    $dettagli_comanda->id_comanda = $data->id_comanda;
    $dettagli_comanda->id_menu = $data->id_menu;

    // create new record
    if ($dettagli_comanda->create()) {
        // set response code - 201 created
        http_response_code(201);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Operazione eseguita con successo."));
    }
    // if unable to add new record
    else {
        // set response code - 503 service unavailable
        http_response_code(503);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Non è stato possibile eseguire l'operazione, riprova più tardi."));
    }
}

// if data is empty
else {
    // set response code - 400 bad request
    http_response_code(400);

    // tell the user
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "C'è stato un problema durante l'elaborazione della richiesta, controlla i dati e riprova."));
}
```

**create function in the object.php file:**

```
// create new record
    function create()
    {
        // sql query
        $query = "INSERT INTO dettagli_comanda 
                    SET id_comanda = :id_comanda,
                        id_menu = :id_menu,
                        stato = '0'";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->id_comanda = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id_comanda));
        $this->id_menu = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id_menu));

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_comanda", $this->id_comanda);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_menu", $this->id_menu);

        // execute query
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have tested PHP functions using Postman, and they work without errors.
I'm sure the problem is in the AJAX call, more specifically in passing values.
Anyone know how to help me?

Also, if I can somehow improve the consistency of my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the params as an an object.  See below:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".add-menuItem-button", function () {
        var id_comanda = $(this).attr("data-id_comanda");
        var id_menu = $(this).attr("data-id_menu");

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/projects/programmazione_web/api/dettagli_comanda/create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {comanda: id_comanda, menu: id_menu },
            success: function (result) {
                // added to order, notify
                bootbox.alert("Aggiunto alla comanda");
            },
            error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                // show error to console
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                bootbox.alert("Errore");
            }
        });
```

Also, make sure you submit the content type below the `data` key like so:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: There's also an issue how they fetch the posted values in PHP. They should (according to this code), fetch it with: `$_POST['comanda']` and `$_POST['menu']` instead of using `file_get_contents('php://input')` and parsing it as it were json (which it won't be). Btw, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I tried that solution, but the error printed in the console is 400. So ```$data->id_comanda``` and ```$data->id_menu``` are empty.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I should just replace ```$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));``` with ```$data = $_POST['comanda'];``` for example?

Comment: @Sergio yes do that and also check my initial post - I added an edit.

Comment: Okay I changed ```json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));``` with ```$data = $_POST['comanda'];``` and ```$data = $_POST['menu'];```; also added ```contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",``` but these changes did not solve the problem

Comment: @Sergio - You can't store both `comanda` and `menu` in the same variable. That will just overwrite the variable. I honestly think you should go through some basic PHP tutorials to learn about strings, variables and how to deal with forms. Then go through some basic Ajax tutorials that uses jquery (there are thousands). There seem to be issues with several of the fundamentals here. Skip the `contentType` comment in the answer since that won't make anything easier.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are probably right, I know I have to study much more. Anyway it was an oversight, because I just did copy and paste to write the comment. I simply named them ```$data``` and ```$data2```. Also in the Ajax call I had ```data: { comanda:id_comanda }``` and ```data2: { menu:id_menu }```

Comment: @Sergio - Well, that's not correct. The data should look like it does in this answer: `data:  {comanda: id_comanda, menu: id_menu }`. In the ajax request, the property `data:` is the payload that will be sent while `data2:` isn't a valid property that will do anything at all. Please read the documentations for the functions you're using (both jquery ajax and PHP)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I thank @AttemptedMastery and @MagnussEriksson for their help and patience.
It took a while, but I found a different solution, however their help was inspirational.

Basically, the problem is that the values stored in `var id_comanda = $(this).attr("data-id_comanda");` and `var id_menu = $(this).attr("data-id_menu");` are strings while `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` accepts JSON content type.

The solution is to use the `JSON.stringify()` function on the data inside the Ajax call as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-menuItem-button", function () {
        var id_comanda = $(this).attr("data-id_comanda");
        var id_menu = $(this).attr("data-id_menu");

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/projects/programmazione_web/api/dettagli_comanda/create.php",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id_comanda: id_comanda,
                id_menu: id_menu
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                // added to order, notify
                bootbox.alert("Aggiunto alla comanda");
            },
            error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                // show error to console
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                bootbox.alert("Errore");
            }
        });
    });
```